# Java - Traversing a linked list only returns null

Tags: java, class, methods, linked-list, system.out

I'm studying linked lists. With some help from the book Cracking the Coding Interview, I created the following code to create a linked lists, add elements to its end and print the elements. However when I run the code, it returns just "null" instead of printing the list i.e. "Sanchez". "Ozil" and "Welbeck". Help?

```
public class CreateLinkedList{

    static class Node{
        String PlayerName;
        Node next = null;

        //Constructor
        Node(String PName){
            PlayerName = PName;
        }

        //Method to insert a Node
        void InsertNodeAtEnd(String PlayerName){
            Node transition = new Node(PlayerName);
            Node n = this;
            while(n.next != null){
                n = n.next;
                }
            n.next = transition;            
            }       

        //Method to print all elements of linked list
        void PrintList(){
            Node n = this;
            while (n.next != null){
                System.out.println(n.PlayerName + "\n");
                n = n.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node first = new Node("Sanchez");
        first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Ozil");
        first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Welbeck");
        first.PrintList();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code as it currently is, and I got `Sanchez` and `Ozil` as output (still missing one, but see @Debasish Jana's answer for that). Where are you getting null?

Comment: Ya just found there was something wrong with my eclipse. Weird I know. Tried in netbeans and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class CreateLinkedList {
static class Node {
    String PlayerName;
    Node next = null;

    // Constructor
    Node(String PName) {
        PlayerName = PName;
    }

    // Method to insert a Node
    void InsertNodeAtEnd(String PlayerName) {
        Node transition = new Node(PlayerName);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = transition;
    }

    // Method to print all elements of linked list
    void PrintList() {
        Node n = this;
        while (n != null) {
            System.out.println(n.PlayerName + "\n");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node first = new Node("Sanchez");
    first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Ozil");
    first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Welbeck");
    first.PrintList();
}
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Sanchez

Ozil

Welbeck
```

Answer (score 0):

In PrintList, iterate for every element,last iteration was missing, so I changed the loop condition

```
void PrintList(){
                Node n = this;
                while (n != null){
                    System.out.println(n.PlayerName + "\n");
                    n = n.next;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is when you're adding to the linked list.

```
Node n = this;
```

this points to the class itself, which is not a node.
You should implement a Node variable within the class that represents the first Node.  So something like this:

```
public class CreateLinkedList{


static class Node{
    //all this stuff seemed fine
    }

Node first = null;//represents first item

    //Method to insert a Node
    void InsertNodeAtEnd(String PlayerName){
        Node transition = new Node(PlayerName);
        Node n = first;
       if(n!=null){
            while(n.next != null){
               n = n.next;
               }
           n.next = transition;            
        }
       else
         first = transition;



    //Method to print all elements of linked list
    void PrintList(){
        Node n = first;
        while (n.next != null){
            System.out.println(n.PlayerName + "\n");
            n = n.next;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node first = new Node("Sanchez");
    first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Ozil");
    first.InsertNodeAtEnd("Welbeck");
    first.PrintList();
}   
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

In printList while iterating use the following as the checking condition:

> n!=null

instead of

> n.next != null

In your code the loop is skipping the last iteration as you are comparing the next node instead of the current node.

The correct method is:

```
//Method to print all elements of linked list
 void PrintList(){
    Node n = this;
    while (n != null){
        System.out.println(n.PlayerName + "\n");
        n = n.next;
    }
}
```